# Caley graphs of gruops and symmetric generating sets

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

There are several examples (of which Wikipedia show at least one) when the Caley graph (G,U) of a group G (where U generates the group) depend on the choice of generating set. Is requiring that the generating set U is symmetric enough to guarantee that the Caley graph only depend on the group (meaning that all Caley graphs with symmetric U are *equal* in some sense), or what other requirements on U would be enough to get uniqueness of the Caley graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different generating sets $S,S'\subset G$ can have **isomorphic** Cayley graphs $\rm{Cay}(G,S)\cong \rm{Cay}(G,S')$ (this is the correct notion of equality of graphs). On the other hand, a group can have many different generating sets, and it should be obvious to you that if you take two generating sets $ S, S'\subset G $ with $|S|\neq |S'|$ then $\rm {Cay}(G, S)\not\cong\rm {Cay}(G, S') $. Your question is related to the so-called **CI problem**. See [this](https://people.math.osu.edu/seress.1/CGAC/slides/palfy.pdf) short presentation for a survey and references.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Cayley graph of $(G,U)$, then the graph of $(G,S)$ where $S=U\cup U^{-1}$ is just the undirected 'version' of the original graph. So different (symmetric) generating sets will still (in general - see DKal's answer) have different graphs as, for example, the Wikipedia page shows for $\mathrm{Dih}(4)$.